# File writing line by line

Tags: java, nio

I'm writing a set of files, inside a directory. This is my code,

```
String directoryName = "logs";
    File directory = new File(String.valueOf(directoryName));
    if (!directory.exists()) {
        directory.mkdir();
    }

    System.out.println("Simulating logs....");
    for (int i = 0; i < 1440; i++) {

        long now = System.currentTimeMillis() + TimeUnit.MINUTES.toMillis(1);

        String fileName = now + ".txt";
        Path filePath = Paths.get(directoryName, fileName);

        LogGenerator generator = new LogGenerator(noOfServers);
        Set<String> logs = generator.generateLog();
        try {
            Files.write(filePath, logs, Charset.forName("US-ASCII"));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
```

The issue is that, all the elements of the set logs are being appended after the first one and being written in the same line. This happens in this line,

```
Files.write(filePath, logs, Charset.forName("US-ASCII"));
```

I want to write each element of the set in a new line. How can i acheive this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is what the [javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#write-java.nio.file.Path-java.lang.Iterable-java.nio.charset.Charset-java.nio.file.OpenOption...-) says about the `write` method:

> "Write lines of text to a file. Each line is a char sequence and is written to the file in sequence **with each line terminated by the platform's line separator**, as defined by the system property line.separator. Characters are encoded into bytes using the specified charset."

I would assume that the method does what the javadoc clearly says it does. Here are some alternative possible explanations:

- The lines were concatenated by the `generateLog()` method.
- There is a mismatch between Java's idea of what the platform line separator is (on the machine where the code is running) and what the app you are using to view the file is expecting.
- You are viewing the output in a context where raw line separator characters are not rendered; e.g. an HTML document ...

Comment: I fixed it, the over ride to the toString method of the object that was written in the logs had a bug.